# Shrink UIImage in bordered UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I draw a border on my UIImageView...

```
[[albumImage layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[[albumImage layer] setBorderWidth:10.0];
```

But those extra 10 pixels are drawn *inside* the image view. Part of my image is cut off! I want to either:

- Shrink the UIImage with a 0.96 factor so it fits inside the border.. or
- Shrink the UIImageView down 10 pixels on each side in IB, then draw the border outside the image view

Using `contentMode`, `transform`, and `contentScaleFactor` haven't been the correct solution. The last two scale the entire image view (including the border). Content mode just changes how the image fits in the view (which has already been set, in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I would add the image view into a container view and draw the border on the container view. If you're doing the container in XIB then you can set the size there. If you're doing it in code, set the image view frame as:

```
imageView.frame = CGRectInset(containerView.bounds, 10, 10);
```